# How do I install python-opencv?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install python-opencv for this code. https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn

How do I do that? When I type pip install --user python-opencv i get

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-opencv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-opencv
```

I managed to install cython and easydict using

```
pip install --user cython
pip install --user easydict
```

Comment: Yes I need to install python-opencv but there isnt any instruction on how i can install python-opencv. i use pip because i always see pip ____. i am new to ubuntu i dunno anything about ubuntu so i need very clear instructions.

Comment: i managed to install easydict and cython using pip install --user

Comment: Okay. Can you please update your question to include details what you have actually tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip already installed,then this would do

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: Your answer is right, AFAICT, but for someone with the same question, who has already discovered `pip` it's probably better to know that if `man pip` doesn't work, then `pip --help` works (with applications in general) and tells you you can do `pip search $terms`. `pip search opencv` shows you that the package you want is probably opencv-python. And that's where the answer comes in. [If you demonstrate how to arrive at answer, the person can solve the problem themselves next time.]. Oh, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks, I would try to quickly adapt to properly present answers.